# Unable to Update or Install new apps (Bug #993407)

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

My issues started earlier today when I ran the Software Updater on my computer which is running the 64-bit version of Ubuntu 14.04.  The update failed and redirected me to the bug tracker for [Bug #993407](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texinfo/+bug/993407).

I have since restarted my computer and tried the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
   libupstart1 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-30-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 84 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.

After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/etc/environment: line 2: PATH: command not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
  install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I thank you in advance for any advice on how to resolve this issue.

**UPDATES:**

I have gotten a bit of assistance from the Ubuntu IRC Channel.  You could see what was done [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2298047&p=13376159#post13376159).  I would have posted the new information directly into this post, but I am unable to do so since it has too many urls.